# Bayesian Classifier

Tags: matlab, classification, bayesian

When using the Bayesian classifier in matlab what’s the best way to avoid over fitting and inaccuracies?

I am using 1000 samples at the moment for the training data of which 750 are "normal" and 250 are "anomalous" (of one specific kind).

Has anyone found a good percentage of which works to train the classifier or does each problem require a specific amount of training data. I would assume the latter but I am struggling to figure out how I can improve the accuracy, what method could I use. Any example would be grateful.

Below is an example of what I am currently using:

```
training_data = data;
target_class = Book2(indX,:)

class  = classify(test_data,training_data, target_class, 'diaglinear')
confusionmat(target_class,class)


% Display Results of Naive Bayes Classification
input = target_class;
% find the unique elements in the input
uniqueNames=unique(input)';
% use string comparison ignoring the case
occurrences=strcmpi(input(:,ones(1,length(uniqueNames))),uniqueNames(ones(length(input),1),:));
% count the occurences
counts=sum(occurrences,1);
%pretty printing
for i=1:length(counts)
disp([uniqueNames{i} ': ' num2str(counts(i))])
end

% output matching data
dataSample = fulldata(indX, :)
```

Comment: Hmm, a BC overfitting? I would suggest looking into choosing the right prior, a strength of BCs is their resistance to overfitting

Comment: http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/7479/overfitting-by-bayesian-methods

Comment: A suggestion I'd have for you is to plot your validation error as you increase the percentage of samples used for training. The minimum of that function should empirically provide you with a reasonably accurate estimate of the point at which you started fitting the noise

Comment: Im not sure on how you choose the prior in matlab with the standard classifier also when you say 'plot the validation error' exactly how is that done?

Comment: hmm, I'm not near my MATLAB machine at the moment, but see if this can help - one of the "overloads" allows you to specify the prior: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classify.html

Comment: a simple way to plot the validation error is to perform "cross validation" where you hold back a certain number of samples during the training (10% is a reasonable number), train on the remaining 90%, then see how you do on the 10% after you build your classifier. Not quite sure exactly what MATLAB strokes youd type in to get that from the standard classify function. shouldn't be too hard to build tho

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but maybe someone arriving here from Google could still benefit from an answer.  I've not used Naive Bayes with Matlab, but have experience in other environments and authored the [ruby nbayes gem](https://github.com/oasic/nbayes).  You've got at least a few questions in here so let's unpack them.

**Overfitting and Accuracy.**  Don't buy the hype -- Naive Bayes is definitely prone to overfitting, so make sure you use cross validation when measuring the validity of your classifier.  I've found that good feature selection (e.g., removing useless terms/tokens) usually boosts accuracy and will also help to reduce overfitting.  And, of course, more data never hurts (but may not help if you already have a lot).

**Class imbalance issues.**  It looks like you are trying to classify new instances as either "normal" or "anomalous".  In general, you want the balance of classes to match what exists in the real world (what you are modelling).  If you choose not to, maybe because anomalous instances are too few, then make sure you manually set the prior distributions on the classes to their real value.

For more detailed info, I highly recommend excerpts from the Stanford IR book: 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html